# How do I override the .value() in a D3 function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```
 d3.select('#ggrade')
   .call(
     d3.slider()
       .value(g_grade)
       .max(100)
       .step(1)
       .axis(true)
       .on("slide", function(evt,value) {
         d3.select('#nodes').text(value);
         if (100 < value + f_grade+ d_grade + e_grade){
            value = 100-f_grade-d_grade-e_grade;
            console.log(value)
         }
         else { g_grade = value;}

         graphdata = [["D", "E", "F", "G"], [e_grade, d_grade, f_grade, g_grade]]
         change(randomData());
         updateweight();
       }
       )

   );
```

My question is how do I override the .value(g_grade) after checking to see whether it hits a few parameters or not. I tried adding ".value(g_grade)" after the .on() function call, but that kicked off a domain error.

Basically I have 4 sliders, and I'm trying to make sure that their sum does not exceed 100 since it's a percentage composition. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update works best on slider if stored as a variable, which can be called again, and the event captured at slideend, eg:

```
let d_grade = 25;
let e_grade = 25;
let f_grade = 25;
let g_grade = 25;

var gSlider = d3.slider()
   .value(g_grade)
   .max(100)
   .step(1)
   .axis(true)
    .on("slideend", function(evt,value) {
    let totalValue = value + f_grade+ d_grade + e_grade

     if (totalValue > 100){

       g_grade = 100 - f_grade - d_grade - e_grade;

     } else {

       g_grade = value;

     }

        gSlider.value(g_grade)
  })


d3.select('#ggrade')
  .call(gSlider)
```

Example: http://bl.ocks.org/tomshanley/e6adabb6403a17990e8f4e39f5bc79eb

Comment: Hmmm, I just tried that but it kicked off an error that said d3(...).value is not a function.  I know all I have to do is access that .value element and manually reassign it, but completely stumped on how to do that.

Comment: Updated the answer with an example

Comment: That worked the text updates properly now. Thank you! You seem to know this far better than I, but is there a way to also keep the slider from moving?  With what you have up there the text and the internal value will stay the maximum, but the slider position will continue to move. I tried setting the newPos and pos but that didn't quite work.

Comment: It will be worth creating a new question to answer that, cheers Tom